# JSON data is read but cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: android, arrays, json

I'm developing an app which reads JSON data. Json Data is parsed but it is not viewing in the listview. Logcat says about a type mismatch. I'm not that much familiar in Json.
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lat=6.421465&lon=81.332396&cnt=10&mode=json

This is my logcat and code. Please hemp me with this.

> org.json.JSONException: Index 1 out of range [0..1)
>   org.json.JSONArray.get(JSONArray.java:263)
>   org.json.JSONArray.getString(JSONArray.java:421)
>   com.is.parsej.ParseJ$GetContacts.doInBackground(ParseJ.java:141)
>   com.is.parsej.ParseJ$GetContacts.doInBackground(ParseJ.java:1)
>   android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)

```
   public class ParseJ extends ListActivity {

         private ProgressDialog pDialog;

            // URL to get contacts JSON
            private static String url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?lat=6.421465&lon=81.332396&cnt=10&mode=json";

            // JSON Node names
            private static final String TAG_COd = "list"; //edited
            private static final String TAG_ID = "dt";    //edited

            private static final String TAG_WEATHER = "weather";
            private static final String TAG_MAIN = "main";
            private static final String TAG_DESC = "description";

            private static final String TAG_TEMP = "temp";
            private static final String TAG_DAY = "day";
            private static final String TAG_MIN = "min";
            private static final String TAG_MAX = "max";
            private static final String TAG_NIGHT = "night";
            private static final String TAG_MORN= "morn";

            private static final String TAG_HUMIDITY = "humidity";

            // contacts JSONArray
            JSONArray contacts = null;

            // Hashmap for ListView
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_parse_j);

                contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                ListView lv = getListView();

                // Listview on item click listener
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
                        // getting values from selected ListItem
                        String weather = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.main))
                                .getText().toString();
                        String Temp = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Descrption))
                                .getText().toString();
                        String Humidity = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.temp))
                                .getText().toString();

                        // Starting single contact activity
                        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                SingleContactActivity.class);
                        in.putExtra(TAG_WEATHER, weather);
                        in.putExtra(TAG_TEMP, Temp);
                        in.putExtra(TAG_HUMIDITY, Humidity);
                        startActivity(in);

                    }
                });

                // Calling async task to get json
                new GetContacts().execute();
            }

            /**
             * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
             * */
            private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    // Showing progress dialog
                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ParseJ.this);
                    pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    pDialog.show();

                }

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                    // Creating service handler class instance
                    ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

                    // Making a request to url and getting response
                    String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

                    Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

                    if (jsonStr != null) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                            // Getting JSON Array node
                            contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_COd);

                            // looping through All Contacts
                            for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                                String humidity = c.getString(TAG_HUMIDITY);

                                // Phone node is JSON Object
                                JSONObject temp = c.getJSONObject(TAG_TEMP);
                                String day = temp.getString(TAG_DAY);
                                String maxTemp = temp.getString(TAG_MAX);
                                String minTemp = temp.getString(TAG_MIN);
                                String morningTemp = temp.getString(TAG_MORN);
                                //edited
                                JSONArray weather = c.getJSONArray(TAG_WEATHER);
                                String main = weather.getString(1);
                                String desc = weather.getString(2); 

                                // tmp hashmap for single contact
                                HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                                contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                                contact.put(TAG_DAY, day);
                                contact.put(TAG_DESC, desc);
                                contact.put(TAG_HUMIDITY, humidity);

                                // adding contact to contact list
                                contactList.add(contact);
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
                    }

                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                    // Dismiss the progress dialog
                    if (pDialog.isShowing())
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            ParseJ.this, contactList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_DAY, TAG_DESC,
                                    TAG_HUMIDITY }, new int[] { R.id.temp,
                                    R.id.main, R.id.Descrption });

                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: check whether the data is valid JSONArray or not... Log your data before the initialization of JSONArray.........

Comment: Yes the whole Data is passed to the LogCat. After that only this exception occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your `JSON` it is just a list of element. Arrays have `[` at the beginning and `]` at the end. look closely at your JSON you may find some array elements there that has `[]`.

weather only has 1 element

```
"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d"}]
```

index out of bounds because you are using

```
   JSONArray weather = c.getJSONArray(TAG_WEATHER);
   String main = weather.getString(1);
   String desc = weather.getString(2);
```

where there is no 1 and 2 in your json array weather, since the weather seems to have only 1 element put it in another json object

```
JSONObject weather = c.getJSONArray(TAG_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
String main = weather.getString("main");
String desc = weather.getString("description");
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Got it right. And got an idea about Json. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
                 JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("list");

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
}
```

change this in your code and let me know, if any issue.

Answer (score 1):

the json is here

> {**"cod":"200"**,"message":0.2809,"city":{"id":1244926,"name":"Hambantota","coord":{"lon":81.1185,"lat":6.1241},"country":"LK","population":0},"cnt":10,"list":[{"dt":1409896800,"temp":{"day":301.95,"min":300.47,"max":302.12,"night":301.31,"eve":301.87,"morn":300.47},"pressure":1020.63,"humidity":88,"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken
>   clouds","icon":"04d"}],"speed":6.47,"deg":243,"clouds":56},{"dt":1409983200,"temp":{"day":301.11,"min":299.62,"max":301.29,"night":299.62,"eve":300.76,"morn":300.13},"pressure":1021.53,"humidity":92,"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered
>   clouds","icon":"03d"}],"speed":6.66,"deg":249,"clouds":48},{"dt":1410069600,"temp":{"day":300.9,"min":299.36,"max":300.9,"night":299.58,"eve":300.2,"morn":299.36},"pressure":1022.25,"humidity":90,"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken
>   clouds","icon":"04d"}],"speed":7.21,"deg":242,"clouds":80},{"dt":1410156000,"temp":{"day":299.47,"min":298.71,"max":300.44,"night":299.5,"eve":299.96,"morn":298.71},"pressure":1023.27,"humidity":98,"weather":[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered
>   clouds","icon":"03d"}],"speed":5.83,"deg":252,"clouds":44},{"dt":1410242400,"temp":{"day":301.38,"min":297.39,"max":301.38,"night":298.36,"eve":300.82,"morn":297.39},"pressure":1012.02,"humidity":0,"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light
>   rain","icon":"10d"}],"speed":3.87,"deg":250,"clouds":76,"rain":0.38},{"dt":1410328800,"temp":{"day":301.77,"min":297.49,"max":301.77,"night":299.44,"eve":301.13,"morn":297.49},"pressure":1011.84,"humidity":0,"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light
>   rain","icon":"10d"}],"speed":4.88,"deg":259,"clouds":27,"rain":0.82},{"dt":1410415200,"temp":{"day":302.15,"min":299.15,"max":302.15,"night":299.43,"eve":300.52,"morn":299.15},"pressure":1011.1,"humidity":0,"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light
>   rain","icon":"10d"}],"speed":6.3,"deg":257,"clouds":64,"rain":1.82},{"dt":1410501600,"temp":{"day":301.52,"min":299.16,"max":301.52,"night":299.36,"eve":300.59,"morn":299.16},"pressure":1011.05,"humidity":0,"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light
>   rain","icon":"10d"}],"speed":8.05,"deg":257,"clouds":50,"rain":2.38},{"dt":1410588000,"temp":{"day":301.26,"min":298.74,"max":301.26,"night":299.53,"eve":300.43,"morn":298.74},"pressure":1010.43,"humidity":0,"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light
>   rain","icon":"10d"}],"speed":7.69,"deg":258,"clouds":33,"rain":1.34},{"dt":1410674400,"temp":{"day":300.01,"min":298.37,"max":300.01,"night":298.48,"eve":298.37,"morn":298.87},"pressure":1010.17,"humidity":0,"weather":[{"id":501,"main":"Rain","description":"moderate
>   rain","icon":"10d"}],"speed":8.36,"deg":253,"clouds":55,"rain":8.91}

and then you get object with tag "cod"

```
contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_COd)
```

"cod":"200"

you will get "200"

how can "200" be converted to JSONArray?
the array structure is just like this
[{"dt":1409896800},{"dt":1409896800},{"dt":1409896800},{"dt":1409896800}]

starts with "[" and end with "]"

Comment: Thanks I got your point. Now I edited the code. (Please have a look) It's giving arrayOutofRange Exception. As I think array Weather has 4 elements. But it says [0-1] is the range.

Answer (score 0):

Exception is self Explaining

```
org.json.JSONException: Value 200 at cod of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

You are converting `String` to `JSONArray` here,

```
contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_COd);
```

`cod` is a String while you're converting it to JSONArray

```
String cod = jsonObj.getJSONString(TAG_COd);
```